# Set Alias to change environment variable

Tags: powershell, environment-variables, alias

I was wondering if it is possible to set an environment variable using an alias command in my profile.

I have multiple remote docker host servers and I would like to be able to switch between them inside one PowerShell window.

I've tried putting this in my Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1 file:

```
New-Alias dockerhost1 $env:DOCKER_HOST = "<dockerhostname1>:2375"
```

But when I open a PowerShell window I get an error

> New-Alias : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '='.

Just wondered if anyone could advise on how I could go about doing this, if it's possible?

Comment: `function dockerhost1 { $env:DOCKER_HOST = "<dockerhostname1>:2375" }`

Comment: Look at `Get-Help about_Aliases`. You don't want an alias; you want a function (see `Get-Help about_Functions`).